# How to update particular column fields with while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**SQL Server 2008**

My SQL table is Like below

```
----------------------------------------
**name  department  fee_paid    id**
----------------------------------------
Farooq  ECE          10000     NULL
Khan    EEE          20000     NULL
Syed    Chemistry    4000      NULL
Syed    Chemistry    14000     NULL
Yousuf  Physics      2000      NULL
Yousuf  Physics      18000     NULL
Zubair  EEE          4000      NULL
----------------------------------------
```

now i wish to fill data in id fields like below

```
----------------------------------------
**name  department  fee_paid    id**
----------------------------------------
Farooq  ECE          10000     1000
Khan    EEE          20000     1001
Syed    Chemistry    4000      1002
Syed    Chemistry    14000     1003
Yousuf  Physics      2000      1004
Yousuf  Physics      18000     1005
Zubair  EEE          4000      1006
----------------------------------------
```

i tried like below but it stores same value in all id fields..I know as i miss my where condition in update query below.But how i use where condition with above table criteria because it has duplicates ?

```
declare @i as int =1000
while @i<=1006
begin
    update flatfile set id=@i
    set @i+=1
end
```

Comment: I am very interested if that would be possible to use recursive CTE for that. If that is possible could someone provide an example pls.

Comment: I've already tired the recursion however, can't get result with distinct names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `ALTER TABLE`?

```
alter table flatfile 
add ID int identity(1000,1)
```

**EDIT** -
if you want to do it in loop:

```
declare @i as int = 1000
while @i<=1006
begin
    update top(1) flatfile set id=@i 
    where id is null;
    set @i+=1
end
```

Comment: I know the way which u said but I want to learn through update query in loop condition only............ and i tried following query and get row numbers but i didnt know how to assign in where condition......                                      `code` select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 0)) from flatfile

Comment: U gave half solution only.....Incase if i my ID column has data in some fields and some fields having null means how your solution  satisfies that criteria.... i just post an example in my question with all NULLs... i looking answer to update ID field using rownumber() or else any other way

Answer (score 3):

To get the ID it's possible to use the `Row_Number` function.

Windowing functions are not allowed in an update script, but we can write an updatable view, or a CTE, and work with it instead:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT [name], [department], [fee_paid], [id]
       , num = Row_Number()
         OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 999
  FROM   table1
)
UPDATE CTE SET
  ID = num;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a7090/8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Place the content in a cursor.
In a loop, retrieve the cursor value and use it in the where condition of the update statement.
You would have a unique id on the assumption that the combination of the name, department and fee_paid is unique.

---